# difference between initialize object implicitly and explicitly on c#

Tags: c#, object, syntax

**This syntax IMPLICITLY calls the default constructor**

```
Order order3 = new Order 
{ 
    OrderID = 124, 
    CustomerName = "leo", 
    OrderAmount= 395.00M
};
```

**This syntax EXPLICITLY calls the default constructor**

```
Order order3 = new Order() 
{ 
    OrderID = 124, 
    CustomerName = "leo", 
    OrderAmount= 395.00M
};
```

Comment: The first syntax saves you two keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

It does the same logic, just creates obj with default constructor.
The only advantage of using explicit syntax is that you can call constructors with a different signature.

For example:

```
Order order3 = new Order("GUID") { 
     OrderID = 124, 
     CustomerName = "leo", 
     OrderAmount= 395.00M
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I'm guessing that the explicit version allows you to have different constructor signatures; pass in a connection string for example.

Answer (score 0):

No difference.
Both parts of code are compiled to:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.OrderID = 124;
order.CustomerName = "leo";
// etc.
```